# How to close a side menu by clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a side menu that is working good. I need help with when menu is opened user can close the menu by click outside it.

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#service-icon-button').click(function() {
if($(this).css("margin-left") == "480px")
{
    $('.service-menu').animate({"margin-left": '-=480'});
    $('#service-icon-button').animate({"margin-left": '-=480'});
}
else
{
    $('.service-menu').animate({"margin-left": '+=480'});
    $('#service-icon-button').animate({"margin-left": '+=480'});
}

});

});
```

below the jsfiddle sample 
https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedcom/1j0wr4pL/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code for close a side menu by clicking outside of it

```js
$(document).click(function (e) {
    var container = $("#service-icon-button");
    if (e.target.id == container[0].id)     // if the target of the click isn't the TOGGLE BUTTON... 
    {

        if ($("#service-icon-button").css("margin-left") == "480px") {
            $('.service-menu').animate({ "margin-left": '-=480' });
            $('#service-icon-button').animate({ "margin-left": '-=480' });
        }
        else {
            $('.service-menu').animate({ "margin-left": '+=480' });
            $('#service-icon-button').animate({ "margin-left": '+=480' });
        }
    }
    else {

        if ($("#service-icon-button").css("margin-left") == "480px") {
            $('.service-menu').animate({ "margin-left": '-=480' });
            $('#service-icon-button').animate({ "margin-left": '-=480' });
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: It works on the first try, but when pressed again, the tab all the way to the right and does not close when clicked outside of it.

Comment: thanks ,it working now ,but user should clicks on the left of #service-icon-button to open again ,far from text and icon .
also there is issue with click on menu when it opend ,it closed !

Comment: In the second else statement you can remove the `+` in front of `+=480`. For me that change worked.

Comment: @AhmedElzelaky Can you mark this answer correct if the answer is useful?

Comment: @MohammadAliRony it was the The closest answer but the issue now that, we need to prevent the condition from being applied when the menu is pressed while opened

Comment: @AhmedElzelaky did you remove `+` in both the statements inside the first else block

Comment: @Ramesh yes , if it working with you can you edit jsfiddle ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener and a condition to check if the menu is opened:

```
$(document).on("click" , function () {

     if($('#service-icon-button').css("margin-left") === "480px")
   {
        $('.service-menu').animate({"margin-left": '-=480'});
        $('#service-icon-button').animate({"margin-left": '-=480'});   
   }
});
```

Comment: Now that i look at it, it's essentially the same thing in a separate listener and if block